# ifstream.read() causing excessive change in stream position

Tags: c++, position, ifstream

```
char Buffer;
std::string FileLocation = "C:\Data.bin";
std::ifstream Stream;
Stream.open(FileLocation);
Stream.read(&MyBuffer, 1);
int begin_of_file = (int)Stream.tellg()
```

Hi, I'm attempting to parse a binary file I created.  In doing so I discovered an odd behavior with ifstream; that is, if I'm at position 0 and I read a single byte, tellg will tell me my current position in the stream is 3585 when it should be 1.  Continuing to read from the stream increments the position as expected and it returns the correct data, but the stream is throwing off my calculations by acting as if there were 3584 positions between 0 and 1.

Is there something that I am missing about this?  Windows adding meta data to the file that is getting picked up?

Comment: There's no error checking in the code you show.  Are you sure the file has opened successfully?  Then unescaped backslash in `FileLocation` can cause you grief.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  Reading from the file gives the expected chars, but not the expected position.

Comment: You're attempting to parse a "binary" file, without opening the file specifying `std::ios::in | std::ios::binary` as the open mode. Interesting. Regardless, this should still work, but I'm genuinely curious what the first two bytes of that file are. Post them in your question. And while you're at it, a *real* [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice as well, otherwise the best you'll get are guesses.